# Continuous bijection from $[0,1]$ to $[0,0.5)\cup (0.5,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Can we have a continuous bijection from $[0,1]$ to $[0,0.5)\cup (0.5,1]$?

Comment: Can you find some topological property that one of the spaces has but the other hasn't?

Comment: Can you make some *connection* between the image of the set and the preimage?

Comment: [IVT](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, because a continuous function sends connected sets into connected sets (connection is a topological property).

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible because the set $[0,0.5) \cup (0.5, 1]$ is the union of two disjoint closed sets. So this space is not connected.

Comment: You mean '*open*' subsets of $[0,1]$, not closed sets, don't you?

Comment: @Berci, I was referring to it as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$.